# swift wants to show interactive SVG map with zoom in, out & user selection features

Tags: ios, swift, svg, maps

I have a map image[image: map image] in svg wants to display it on the screen so user can zoom in zoom out can touch on some specific points & I'll show up some popups.
Anyone have idea that how can I achieve this I'm also attaching a png photo of that map.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the satellite view of **google maps** editing in the image is apparently is not possible

Comment: there's already an app name 'Dubai Metro' which is using svg map image, its possible that I know only thing to know is how?